# Jquery Animation on click, stop it repeating on multiple clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got code like this:

```
$("#ajax_stuff").load("/site/method", $('.myselector').serializeArray()).delay(100).fadeOut('slow').delay(20).fadeIn('slow');
```

And basically, that is triggered each time someone clicks a checkbox in a list of checkboxes. What happens is if someone quickly clicks 20 checkboxes in a row, the effect repeats 20 times.

Ideally i just want it to do one effect for the last  box they clicked and then stop.

I've tried

```
$("#ajax_stuff").load("/site/method", $('.myselector').serializeArray()).stop(true,true).delay(100).fadeOut('slow').delay(20).fadeIn('slow');
```

But that doesn't seem to do anything. Any advice would be very gratefully received!

Answer (score 0):

```
var delay = (function () {
 var timer = 0;
 return function(callback, ms){
 clearTimeout (timer);
 timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
      };
    })();
$(function(){
    $("/*CHECKBOX SELECTOR*/").on("click",function(){
        delay((function(){
                      $("#ajax_stuff").load("/site/method", $('.myselector').serializeArray()).stop(true,true).delay(100).fadeOut('slow').delay(20).fadeIn('slow');}),1000);
});
});
```

setTimeout is your friend in this case, I think.  I haven't used it on checkbox clicks, but you might have to changed the event handler from click to select or something.  I tried to put it in `jsfiddle` just now, but it's crashed maybe?  Not loading regardless.

Comment: Sorry for coming back so late to this. This doesn't work i'm afraid, i still get the multiple blinking.